# Python can't/won't use a directory path properly

Tags: python, system, adb

out of laziness I decided to write a Python script that could ADB push all my music from my computer to my phone. I got the music transfer to work using an adb push helper function:

```
def push(push,dir): # adb push helper.
    cmd = 'adb push {} {}'.format(pipes.quote(push),pipes.quote(dir))   
    os.system(cmd)
# end def
```

This thing works freaking great with my transfer function:

```
def transfer(rootdir):
    print "Creating directories on-device now..."
    for artist in os.listdir(rootdir):
        if artist != ignore:
            artistpath = os.path.join(mediadir,artist)  
            sysartist = os.path.join(rootdir,artist)    
            for album in os.listdir(sysartist):                                                     
                if album != ignore:  # ignore = ".DS_Store"
                    albumpath = os.path.join(artistpath,album)
                    md(albumpath) # md is a helper to make directories. 
                # end if
            # end for
        # end if
    # end for
    print "Pushing music now..."
    sleep(5)
    push(rootdir,mediadir)    # Assume rootdir and mediadir are iTunes directory 
                              # and /sdcard/Music, with mediadir being a global. 
# end def
```

That goes right on through. No problem. But when I call it in my main ADB push function, I get a "cannot stat /Users/x/Desktop/thisandthatfile: no such file or directory".

My main pusher function looks like this:

```
num = int(raw_input("How many files or directories to push?: "))
    for i in range(num):
        pushfile = raw_input("Input source file/directory: "); prettypush = os.path.join(pushfile)
        dir = raw_input("Input destination directory: "); prettydir = os.path.join(dir)
        push(prettypush,prettydir)
    # end for
```

What am I doing wrong in my pusher function vs. my transfer function? I originally thought it was because the pusher function was feeding push paths relative to the Python script and not the system (as opposed to transfer(), which only feeds it absolute system paths...) but fixing that with os.path.join() didn't work.

Comment: please don't use semicolons `;` in your Python code. One statement per line, please.

Comment: Why are you calling `os.path.join(pushfile)` and `os.path.join(dir)`? Try those calls in interactive mode; they do something almost, but not quite, entirely unlike what you want.

Comment: @user2357112 Using those in interactive mode produces the exact same results I expected; a directory path. Unfortunately, shell/adb still fails on using any file I throw at it but ONLY when I use pusher().